# Android Speech Recognition Does not identify short words when using extra language

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

The speech recognizer intent was working fine till recently; it suddenly stopped accepting short words i.e "yes", "no" etc. The issue seems to get fixed if you stick to English-only input, but I want to accept both English and Swedish input. My current implementation is as follows;

```
public void getSpeechInput() {
    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "sv-SE");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);

    speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);

}
```

has something changed on google's end? do I need to implement this differently? I have tried removing all the extra intents leaving only `recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "sv-SE");` intent, but still It did not fix the issue.

Comment: This is unanswerable, because the recognizer is not the same across all devices.  It's an intent, it can be switched out.  What you're asking for would be implementation specific, and we have no idea what speech recognizer you have

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm using [Android Speech Recognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer), and this occurs on multiple devices, tested on at least 8 phones so far.

Comment: No, you aren't.  That's the API to call the speech recognizer.  It calls another app to do the actual recognition-  and that app can vary between any two devices, it's not the OS itself doing it (it can even be replaced by the user.  Just like the keyboard or dialer).  And the bug/reason for this will be based on that application's implementation.  Now Google does provide an implementation of it that's fairly common to use, but it isn't universal.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks to your input, I was able to figure it that the recognizer is [Speech services by google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts&hl=en&gl=US) but when I test my scenario on google chrome voice search which uses the same recognizer, this issue does not exist., it recognizes English and Swedish both really well. it has to be an issue with my implementation now, isn't it?